# websocket messages appears at once rather than individual messages

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I want my backend send progress message to UI via websocket.
My problem is all messages,which produced by calling

> automate_algorithm()

function appear **together at once at the end** of process, instead of appear one by one. Is there any wrong with my code.

This class create a dictionary which key is project id, and value is the opened websocket

```
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(
            self
    ):
        self.connections: dict[str, WebSocket] = {}

    async def connect(
            self,
            id: str,
            websocket: WebSocket
    ):
        """To add new open socket to memory storage

        Args:
            id:(str)the
        """
        await websocket.accept()
        self.connections[id] = websocket
    
    async def disconnect(self, id: str):
        if id in self.connections:
            await self.connections[id].close(code=100,reason=None)
            del self.connections[id]

    async def send_response(
            self,
            id: str,
            data: str,
            status:str='running'
    ):
        print(
            f"tries to send response for client with id :{id}. Response is {data}")
        try:
            await self.connections[id].send_json(data=dict(
                timestamp=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()),
                message=data,
                id=id,
                status=status
            )
            )
            if status=="completed":
                await self.disconnect(id)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            self.disconnect(id)


    manager = ConnectionManager()#create a context for web socket manager
```

This method get user HTTP request, and start process

```
@router.websocket("/auto_algo/{client_id}")
async def auto_algo(
        websocket: WebSocket,
        client_id: str,
):
    
    await manager.connect(client_id, websocket)
    
    # HANDLE FUNCTION*****
    await automate_algorithm(idt=client_id)
```

This is the main method which produce the messages,that should write in websocket.

```
async def send_message_to_socket(
        client_id: str,
        what: str,
        status:str='running'
):
    global manager

    await manager.send_response(client_id, what,status)



# automate to algorithm ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
async def automate_algorithm(idt,language='en'):
    from controllers.dispatcher_controller import send_message_to_socket
    
    await  send_message_to_socket(client_id=idt,what="process starting")#This message appear at start correctly
    
    mds2 = create_mds(idt,mapper=False)
    await  send_message_to_socket(client_id=idt,what="main_data_structure 2 created...")#the rest of message appear together at the end of process
    
    sample_data = create_sample_data(idt,mapper=False)
    await  send_message_to_socket(client_id=idt,what="sample data created...")
    
    corr = correlation_matrix(idt,mapper=False)
    await  send_message_to_socket(client_id=idt,what="correlation created...")
    
    mds3 = accomplish_mds(idt,mapper=False)
    await  send_message_to_socket(client_id=idt,what="main_data_structure 3 created...")
```

Comment: what i know is use `while` in websocket route, your current websocket ack once per request not live

Comment: you were right, if the communication type is interactive. I mean user send something to server, and server process hist message, then send response to him. But in my problem, server want to informed user his process status.

Answer (score 1):

When the code is executed, the control is never returned to the event loop. There is an easy fix for this; add some `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to semi-manually return control to the event loop, so it has a chance to execute the send() method of other tasks.So I add `await asyncio.sleep(0)` right after each `await  send_message_to_socket(...)` line, and the code works correctly